# short circuit in java

Tags: java, logical-operators, short-circuit-evaluation

I thought I understood that using short circuit operators that the order of precedence is important however I am having difficulty in understanding why the following code occurs:

```
line 3. false && true || true   // this returns true
line 4. false && true |  true  //  this returns false
```

I am correct in stating that the code on line 4 will return false because the evaluation is from right to left. However if line 3 has the left to right evaluation, why does it return a true? Using just two short circuit operators is fine but using three, I am somewhat stuck on the logic. No pun intended.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and explain your understanding of the difference of `||` and `|`.

Comment: `||` has lower precedence than `&&`.  But `|` has **higher** precedence than `&&`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Consider precedence: `false && true || true` would be the same as `(false && true) || true` which boils down to `false || true` and thus `true`. On the other hand `false && true | true` boils down to `false && (true | true)` and thus `false && true` and finally `false`.

Comment: So my understanding is | has more order of precedence that || so false&&true|true would return true because the true|true is calculated first thus leaving false&&true which returns false. This calculation is right to left. So in my head I see false&&true||true as one calculation based on order of precedence thus the short circuit stops immediately at false and does not continue to make a calculation with the true||true section of the code. I thus should see it as two separate calculations. I guess this something I will have to get used to. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Remember [operator precedence](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-ed3e261c0601a32133c517c16766b172) in Java. `|` is evaluated before `&&`, but `||` is evaluated after `&&`. Therefore, the first one would evaluate as `(false && true) || true` which would equal `true`, while the second one would evaluate as `false && (true | true)`, which evaluates to false.

Comment: Thanks, the brackets make the whole world of difference.